# Windows .NET Service - OnSessionChange event seems quite unreliable

Tags: c#, windows, service, authentication

I'm writing a windows service in C# that needs to keep track of the current active logged-in user. To do this, I've overridden the OnSessionChange event, in order to note when users log in, log off, or locks the computer. This usually works, most of the time, however sometimes the service looses track of the active user. In my log files, I can see that the problem is the OnSessionChange method. I output some log information every time this function is called, and apparently, the OnSessionChange calls sometime come in the wrong order. That is, if a user locks the computer and then quickly logs in again, it sometimes occurs that the two OnSessionChange-calls this results in get called in the wrong order (e.g. first an unlock event, then a lock event).

Does anyone know why this happens? And is there any workaround for this problem?

Edit: Here is some sample code, to make it a bit clearer (hopefully):

```
protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
{
    try
    {
        var user = _getUserName(changeDescription.SessionId);

        if (changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionLock ||
            changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionLogoff ||
            changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.ConsoleDisconnect)

            LogText(String.Format("{0} locked at {1}\r\n", user, DateTime.Now));

        else if (changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionUnlock ||
                 changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.SessionLogon ||
                 changeDescription.Reason == SessionChangeReason.ConsoleConnect)

            LogText(String.Format("{0} unlocked at {1}\r\n", user, DateTime.Now));

        base.OnSessionChange(changeDescription);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogText("Exception: " + e);
    }
}
```

(the functions _getUserName and LogText are not shown, but they do what their names suggest. Also, I never get exceptions, so the try-catch-block is there just to verify that I in fact do not get any.)

Now, sometimes, in my log I get things like this:

```
UserA unlocked at 18.01.2015 08:40:29
UserA unlocked at 18.01.2015 08:44:28
UserA locked at 18.01.2015 08:44:28
```

This is what happened this morning. UserA logged in, then locked and immediately (I think) logged in again. But the two last events were fired in the wrong order, so after this sequence, my service mistekenly thought UserA was gone.

Often, I get several unlock-events in a row, like this one from yesterday:

```
UserA unlocked at 17.01.2015 10:55:26
UserA unlocked at 17.01.2015 10:55:26
UserA unlocked at 17.01.2015 10:56:33
```

Or I can get several lock-events in a row, which probably means that I'm missing one or more unlock-events in between them:

```
UserA unlocked at 17.01.2015 09:29:35
UserA locked at 17.01.2015 10:25:28
UserA locked at 17.01.2015 10:30:20
```

Comment: I think showing some part of the code itself might help us understand what you're talking about. While i do know about the OnSessionChange, I think looking into the general login/logoff concept in your program might help me (or others) answer you.

Comment: OK, I'll add some code

Comment: Your code doesn't check for every possible value of changeDescription.Reason (i.e., RemoteConnect, RemoteDisconnect, SessionRemoteControl will result in no log output). Perhaps it would be useful to log these events too, to give a complete picture of what the system is doing and possibly help with diagnosing the problem?

Comment: Actually, I do have another else-branch in my code do to just that (I just removed it here to shorten it a bit). Basically, it's just an "else LogText("Some other reason: " + changeDescription.Reason)". It never happens.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am getting the same thing (I too have a service that does the exact same thing as your code)... sometimes it works... sometimes it doesn't.  What I also see is when the OS is creating a profile, OnSessionChange doesn't get called at all.

Comment: Just a comment for anyone else who comes across this post with a similar issue, I found that `SessionChangeReason.ConsoleConnect` should be ignored for this scenario, and (in my limited testing) removing it solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

this.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent must be set to true, default value is false.